# Is tree-shaking supported when importing colors from material-ui?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, gatsby

I am using material-ui with Gatsby and I'd like to know tree-shaking would be retained if I tried the below:

```
import { purple, green } from '@material-ui/core/colors';
```

Comment: Please add more information to understand better.

Answer (score 0):

From a quick glance through the [docs](https://material-ui.com/guides/minimizing-bundle-size/#when-and-how-to-use-tree-shaking). I don't see any reference to colors or any exception to that. Therefor I would assume that you can do the same as you would with any other import from Material-UI.

Remember that tree shaking only works in the production build, after several optimizations are performed.

Comment: Is there some way to check if the tree-shaking worked during production?

Comment: Tree shaking is an optimization to reduce the size of the bundle. I am not an expert but I would try to do something like this:
  1- Import all colors `import colors from '@material-ui/core/colors'`. And check the bundle size;
  2- Import like you did in you code. Check the bundle size and see if it's smaller than in the first step.

Again, I'm not an expert in these kinds of monitoring/optimization